# Getting time difference between 2 datetimes in Laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I have 2 datetimes, the first is a user's last login date

```
{{ $message->recipient->last_login }}
```

which comes out like "2017-05-11 02:56:18" in the datetime format, and the current time

```
{{ date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}
```

which comes out in the same format.

Essentially what I want is to get the time difference between the two times.

Something like

```
@if (the time difference between the 2 dates is less than 10 minutes)
do this
@endif
```

Comment: use Carbon class

Comment: here's api for reference- http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

Answer (score 7):

You must choose Carbon dates.
Add following in your controller and pass it on to blade.

```
$currentTime = Carbon::now();
```

In blade template use this as follows:

```
@if($currentTime->diffInMinutes($message->recipient->last_login) < 10)
    // your code
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simplest one, Here we here we are getting seconds from time using `strtotime`.

**Laravel blade syntax:**

```
{{intval((strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))-strtotime("2017-05-11 02:56:18"))/60)}}
```

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/791847)

```
<?php

//getting time difference in seconds.
$secondsDifference=strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))-strtotime('2017-05-11 02:56:18');
//converting seconds to minutes.
echo intval($secondsDifference/60);
```